# Pass binary data into PHP system() command

Tags: php, imagemagick

Is it possible to hand binary data into `system()` like below?

```
$contents = file_get_contents("http://somesite.com/image.jpg");
$out = system("{$contents} | convert - -fuzz 10% -trim jpeg:-");
```

When I go into the terminal and execute `cat filename | convert - -fuzz 10% -trim jpeg:-` it returns binary data to STDOUT... but when I `echo()` or `print_r()` the data above, it's always empty.

Comment: try `passthru` instead of system..

Comment: `passthru` returns `void` and auto echos to the browser. Don't think that's the right one.

Comment: Ahh right you are, i was remebering the mention about using it to handle binary data... shoulda reread the doc before mentioning it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use base64:

   ```
   system('echo ' . base64_encode($contents) . " | base64 -d | convert - -fuzz 10% -trim jpeg:-");
   ```
2. You probably ask a separated question for that

Comment: This is why I <3 StackOverflow. Definitely would not have thought to do this. Thank you! 7 minutes to accept. Cheers.

Comment: @Jordan Arseno: I'm sure it will be a trigger for you since now: if you have a binary data and the underlying command doesn't accept binary but text data only - then there is a sign to think about serialization

Comment: @Jordan Arseno: uhm, what actually?